# How to apply list.index() (or similar) to more than one lists to find position of a pair?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, indexing

Given two lists e.g.

```
x = ['a','b','c','d', 'e']

y = [1 ,2 ,3 ,4, 2]
```

If I want to get the position of a given item in `one` of the columns, I can simply use index()

```
x.index('b')
```

What if I want to get the position of a certain *pair* (as a `list`, `tuple`, or `dict`, whichever works best) of items in both rows (at the same position in each column)? e.g. "find me the position of the pair ('b', 2)"

List `y` may contain repeated values, so I am precluded from logical ANDing the result of two `.index()` calls for each list.

What I am actually dealing with are columns of an `openpyxl` workbook, but the above example illustrates more succinctly.

Comment: If only one of your lists can contain duplicates, just search for half of your target value in the other (unique) list. After you find the index, you can double check that the other half of the pair exists at the same index in the list with duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use zip:

```
In [100]: x = ['a','b','c','d', 'e']

In [101]: y = [1 ,2 ,3 ,4, 2]

In [102]: zip(x,y)).index(('b',2)
Out[102]: 1

In [103]: zip(x,y)
Out[103]: [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4), ('e', 2)]
```

Comment: Your `list` calls are not needed in Python 2 (which this question is tagged with), as `zip` returns a list already. To get behavior like Python 3's `zip` (which returns an iterator), use `itertools.izip`. and speaking of that behavior, you could use `next((index for index, pair in enumerate(itertools.izip(x, y)) if pair == ("b", 2)), None)` to get the index of the first matching element without creating a list of all the pairs.

Answer (score 1):

While a recursive solution might not be wise on a large input size as Python's maximum recursion depth will probably be reached, I thought I'd share a solution anyway, if nothing more than just to illustrate a different way of approaching the problem:

```
def pair_position(list_1, list_2, pair, index=0):
    if set([list_1[index], list_2[index]]) == set(pair):
        return index
    else:
        return pair_position(list_1, list_2, pair, index + 1)
```

Comment: This will terminate (with an `IndexError`) when `list_1` or `list_2` is empty, since `list_1[0]` and `list_2[0]` won't be available. Since you're slicing one item off the lists each time, it's guaranteed to terminate. Note however that it's much more computationally expensive than an iterative approach (e.g. using `zip`), since the slicing copies the lists (requiring `O(N**2)` time and space).

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks for the insight, I've edited the answer taking this on board!